# JQL query that shows the tasks which have new comments on them

Tags: jql

I work for a university and my group uses JIRA to maintain our technology helpdesk. We often send messages to customers and wait days to hear a response. I am looking for a filter that will show all the open tasks which are assigned to me and have a new comment from someone other than me. This way I don't have to look through all of my tasks, I can easily tell from this filter, whether any of my tickets now require a response from me.

So far I have this search:

```
assignee = currentUser() AND status != Done AND 
           updatedDate > startOfDay(-1d) AND updatedDate < endOfDay(-0d)
```

Answer (score 1):

**It doesn't look like Jira provides a way to access number of comments, last comment date, etc.** The closest thing I could find in [their reference](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwarecloud/advanced-searching-fields-reference-764478339.html) was `Comment` which only checks the text of a comment.

### Possible Alternatives

- **Add yourself as a watcher of the Jira issues and setup email notifications.** This is what I do to manage my Jira issues. I setup a `Jira` folder in my email and an automated filter to move all Jira notifications into it. Then I just look through that folder multiple times per day. The downside is you'll keep more notifications than you actually need or care about.
- **Use Jira's REST API**. If you or someone at your school has some programming knowledge, you could probably use the Jira API. Potential solution:

  1. Use the [search](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/#api-api-3-search-get) endpoint to get a list of issues. You can pass JQL to the API to filter the issues.
  2. Use the [get issue](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/#api-api-3-issue-issueIdOrKey-get) endpoint to get the details of each issue returned from the search. Within those details are all the comments on the issue, including the time the comment was posted.

Comment: I currently do have email notifications setup. Although, there are many notifications besides comment changes that get sent.      Many of the techs are students and while working around their classes they need something as efficient as possible to see whether someone has excepted an appointment or have asked for something new.         They often come to the office, find a task they can work on without realizing that something else has come out of the holding pattern it has been in. This leads to disappointed customers.

Comment: Hmm, I see what you mean @Insomniac. Unfortunately it doesn't look like Jira offers a way to do that easily. Maybe you could try getting creative with email filters? I believe new comment notifications will have the text "added a new comment" so a filter with that text and the from address for your Jira account might be able to give you _something_ useful. I'm sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: That's a great idea with the filters! I will look into that. Thank you @rparr

Comment: You're welcome, I hope that works for you, @Insomniac.